# Prevent deselect of xtype:checkbox based on condition in ExtJS 5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs5

ExtJS 5.1

In `xtype: 'checkbox'`

I want to add a condition before deselect checkbox based on condition. According to my research, I got only one event `change` that fire when we check or uncheck check box. I can get checkbox is true or false.

But i want to fire event before deselect of check, so that i can add a condition and if condition is false then i return false and checkbox will not be unchecked.

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Then you can validate on the viewmodel. Are you using MVC? Then you can validate on the record field bind to the formfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "beforecheck" event, indeed, so you have to override the [`onBoxClick`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-method-onBoxClick) method like this:

```
Ext.define('Checkbox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
    onBoxClick: function() {
        if (this.checked && !this.uncheckCondition()) {
            alert('This checkbox cannot be unchecked because....');
            return;
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    uncheckCondition: function() {
        var OK_to_uncheck = false;
        return OK_to_uncheck;
    }
});
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sro

Note that it is a good idea to let the user know why they cannot uncheck the checkbox, otherwise they might think it is just not working. With this in mind, I would instead consider making the checkbox disabled or [`readOnly`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-readOnly) when the cannot-uncheck condition is met.

**UPDATE**

You can actually enhance the checkbox class with "beforeuncheck" event like this:

```
Ext.define('Checkbox', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Checkbox',
    onBoxClick: function() {
        if (this.checked && this.fireEvent('beforeuncheck', this) === false) {
            return;
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And then use:

```
new Ext.form.field.Checkbox({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    boxLabel: 'I am too clever checkbox',
    listeners: {
        beforeuncheck: function() {
            alert('No, you cannot uncheck me, he he :)');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/srq

Comment: Definitely - prevent the user from trying to change the checkbox, instead of trying to veto a change.